# How do I make JavaScript's replaceAll() treat strings with both lower case and upper case as if they were lower case?

Tags: javascript, uppercase, case-insensitive, lowercase, replaceall

In my `<div contenteditable="true">`, the user can type the word "*star*" and the word gets immediately replaced by a star symbol.

If the user types "star" in all lower case letters, this will be displayed: ★

If the user types it with all upper case letters, this will be displayed: ☆

What I need: If the user types the word "star" with a mixture of lower and upper case letters (examples: staR, Star, STaR...), this should be displayed: ★

My first thought was using `toLowerCase()`, but since the conversion happens `onInput`, and it only converts the text once the whole word is typed, using it will make it impossible to type "STAR", all upper case.

Any ideas?

I am open to `jQuery` solutions.

Here is my code:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38u7qjxL/1/)

```js
// Autofocus the div:
document.getElementById("editableDiv").focus();

// Makes the conversion possible:
String.prototype.allReplace = function(obj) {
  var retStr = this;
  for (var x in obj) {
    retStr = retStr.replace(new RegExp(x, 'g'), obj[x]);
  }
  return retStr;
};

// Converts
function convert() {
  var str = document.getElementById("editableDiv").innerHTML;
  var white = str.allReplace({
    'STAR': '☆',
    'DIAMOND': '◇'
  });
  var black = white.allReplace({
    'star': '★',
    'diamond': '◆'
  });

  document.getElementById("editableDiv").innerHTML = black;

  // Move caret to the end:
  var contentEditableElement = document.getElementById("editableDiv");
  var range, selection;
  if (document.createRange) {
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);
    range.collapse(false);
    selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  } else if (document.selection) {
    range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);
    range.collapse(false);
    range.select();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  outline: 0;
  line-height: 2;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="editableDiv" contenteditable spellcheck="false" oninput="convert();"></div>
```

Comment: So you are using a reg exp, add the case flag `'gi'`

Answer (score 1):

First I would recommand to use the existant [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/replaceAll).

Second you ARE using regexp ! Don't worry it's not that complicated ( for your purpose )
I suggest you to do so in 2 steps :

1 - Replace all 'STAR' with ☆

2 - Then replace "**without taking care of the case**" 'star' with ★

And "**without taking care of the case**" means just to use the flag `i` in the regexp ;)

```js
function replaceMyStuff(str) {
  var r = str.replaceAll('STAR', '☆')
             .replaceAll(/star/gi, '★')
             .replaceAll('DIAMOND', '<>')
             .replaceAll('stuff', 'replacedStuff');
  return r;
}

console.log(replaceMyStuff('star STAR StAr STAR STAr stuff'));
```

If your are more confortable with it you can write :

```
 new RegExp('star', 'gi')
```

It's basically the same as `/star/gi`

Then you can use it to replace all that you want :

```
 var str = document.getElementById("editableDiv").innerHTML;
 var replacedString = replaceMyStuff(str);
```

Comment: Using my code, do I have to replace the line `'star': '★',` for `/star/gi, '★'`? Because I tried that, and it doesn't work. I am probably doing something obviously wrong...

Comment: You should try to understand what you are doing ... People won't give you the final code ...  Even if it's what I almost done ... Check the answer I've updated it ...

Answer (score -1):

You can run checks against a target string using the strict equality comparison (`===`) operator, like this:

```
if (string.toLowerCase() === 'star') {

  if (string === 'STAR') {
    output = '☆';
  }

  else {
    output = '★';
  }
}
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const paragraphs = [...document.getElementsByTagName('p')];

const convertParagraph = (paragraph) => {

  let paragraphArray = paragraph.textContent.split(' ');
  
  for (let i = 0; i < paragraphArray.length; i++) {
  
    if (paragraphArray[i].toLowerCase() === 'star') {
    
      if (paragraphArray[i] === 'STAR') {
        paragraphArray[i] = '☆';
      }
    
      else {
        paragraphArray[i] = '★';
      }
    }
  }
  
  paragraph.textContent = paragraphArray.join(' ');
}

paragraphs.forEach(paragraph => convertParagraph(paragraph));
```

```html
<div>
<p>STAR This is a test.</p>
<p>star This is another test.</p>
<p>sTAr This is a third test.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: But the user will be able to type things other than "star". I don't want't to convert any other text except "star", "STAR", and any mixture of both. How could I implement this in my code?

Comment: In order to use the conditions above, you could do something like: 1) grab the entire text; 2) split it into an array using the spaces as separators; 3) loop through the array checking / processing each element; 4) join the array back into a string. That's one approach which doesn't involve regex. Or you can choose one of the answers on this page which use regex (I upvoted @Seba99's which I thought was very good).

Comment: I've added a working example to show what I mean in the comment above.